# Logout from AppStore on iOS Simulator

Tags: ios5, ios-simulator, storekit

Since 5.0, iOS simulator has StoreKit support so you can debug your In-App purchases without device. But, it has one issue. Once logged in (make In-App purchase) I can't change AppStore login. Settings has not "AppStore" item, so I can't "logout" from account.

I tried to delete application from simulator, restart simulator, delete test user from iTunesConnect — no success.

[Screen of the problem](http://grab.by/bbYp)

Any idea?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

There is another way to log out from that sandbox account without "Reset Content & Settings" . Just remove the files from the following path in your home directory :

```
~/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator/5.0/Library/com.apple.itunesstored
```

You may also need to restart the Simulator for the change to take effect.

This just removes the stored information about iTunes from Simulator. So it doesn't delete any apps in the Simulator. It works cool :)

Comment: This no longer seems to work in Simulator 6.0. Any other workarounds?

Comment: @jemmons It still works in Simulator 6.0 - you need to adjust the path.

Comment: You'll need to quit the simulator first, too. At least, you do with 6.1.

Comment: Kudos.  Just what I was looking for.

Comment: For 6.1: `rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator/6.1/Library/com.apple.itunesstored/`

Comment: @plindberg When typing commands that start with `rm -rf ~...` make sure you treat your space bar as if it were the trigger of a loaded gun, pointed at your home directory... if you type `rm -rf ~ /Lib...` on accident, well... `rm` will quickly and studiously do its job and erase your home folder.  **Much safer to `cd` into the dir, and only  then `rm` the file with the relative path.**

Comment: @Tim: Yup.  [This project](https://github.com/MrMEEE/bumblebee-Old-and-abbandoned/commit/a047be85247755cdbe0acce6f1dafc8beb84f2ac) had a typo that caused `/usr` to be deleted.

Answer (score 33):

Try to "Reset content & settings"
[image]

Comment: This helps, thanks. But maybe there is another way to logout from AppStore?

Comment: I doubt there is another way to do this in simulator. Please mark my answer as working :)

Comment: WHAT THE.. Apple? Seriously, there isn't any option to do this? Do we really have to lose every app settings to simply logout from an iTunes Connect account?! Now we're 2016 with Xcode 8.1 and still not the option!

Answer (score 6):

Simulator 6.0 stored information location:

```
~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Library/com.apple.itunesstored/
```

Update for 6.1:

```
~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Library/com.apple.itunesstored/
```

Answer (score 1):

With iOS 7 Apple appear to have removed the ability to test In App Purchases using the simulator. Whatever you do (including removing the files in the relevant `com.apple.itunesstored` simulator directory) you always get the "Could not connect to iTunes store" error when trying to request the product identifiers.

Testing on a device works fine.

**UPDATE**: I have found that the regular "iPhone Retina (4-inch)" simulator works, but the 64bit simulator doesn't. Very odd.

Comment: Just press cancel if you get that error. The error is spurious.

Answer (score 0):

To logout from iOS simulator using xCode 6.3.1, go to Setting -> Safari -> Clear History and Website Data.

Comment: I didn't see this "Edit/Delete Apple ID" option under Settings/Safari. I do see "Clear History and Website Data", but that doesn't seem to work. :-/