# In-App Purchasing Changing Test User on the Simulator

Tags: ios, testing, in-app-purchase

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Logout from AppStore on iOS5 Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028472/logout-from-appstore-on-ios5-simulator)

I've been working on this app recently which has In-app purchasing.  I mostly set up the IAP stuff a couple weeks ago and am just now coming back to finish it up.  When I first started working with this code, I had everything set up to connect to a Test User account and make fake purchases in sandbox mode.  It was all working great, even in the simulator (contrary to some information I've seen on here), but in trying to figure out how to re-test some purchases I deleted the test user I had been using.  This old, deleted test user is still being used by my iOS simulator and I can't seem to figure out how to change settings in the simulator to a different account (assuming there is a way).  Anyone have any ideas there?

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried the followings:

1. Delete the app on the simulator before running it again from Xcode.
2. On the simulator, under iOS Simulator menu, select Reset Content and Settings...