# iOS - How can I change my account when testing inapp purchase?

Tags: ios

I am trying to test an inapp purchase. And it is asking my login credentials. I can't seem to recover my password for my test user. So I was trying to log in as another user.

But I don't see a way to change users. Would anyone know how I can try to log in as a different account when testing the buying of an inapp purchase?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sign out of your test account under Settings -> iTunes & App Store

Comment: thanks, just to clarify, the settings - is that in iTunes, or on the app interface somewhere?

Comment: Its in the actual Settings app

Comment: @heinst if it is something I set on the app, how can I set this on the simulator?

Comment: @rjowens actually, you can. You can do this through a test account.

Comment: for the simulator: [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028472/logout-from-appstore-on-ios-simulator)